# Understanding HTTP status response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose I have **an api.js**:

```
const {somefunction} = require('../controllers/some-controller');
app.get('/data/', somefunction);
```

**some-controller.js:**

```
exports.somefunction = async (req, res,next) => {
    const someVariable = req.params.variable
    try {
        console.log('status',res.statusCode) **//status code is: 200**
        const Details = await collectionName.find({}).exec()
        res.send(Details)
    } catch {
        console.log('status',res.statusCode) **//Here also,status code is: 200**
        next(ApiError.dbError('Internal Server Error')); //middleware for error handling gives output 
                                                         //as ApiError { code: 500, message: 
                                                         //'Internal Server Error' }
        return;
    }
};
```

Say I wrote some wrong variable name in **res.send(Detaaal)** and it goes to catch block
Here even in catch block status code is 200.

I'm trying to understand at what condition is status code different. Why is status code response on fail inside catch block didn't give me 500 status code.

Comment: What does `ApiError.dbError` return?

Comment: I figured it out on how it can return me 500 error.
In catch block if i console:

catch {
        console.log('status',res.statusCode) //Here also,status code is: 200
        next(ApiError.dbError('Internal Server Error'));
        console.log('status',res.statusCode)  //Here also,status code is: 500
        return;
    }

From APIError's staus code I get the status code and set it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 is the default code and nothing has happened that would change that.

You haven't written code to change it and, while an exception has been thrown, you caught it, so it never hits Express' own `catch` logic which would set a 500 error.

The `next` function, on the other hand, *does* appear to change it, but you are looking at the value *before* running that function.

Answer (score 1):

sorry about my poor english

your logic in here cause the problem you are getting everything in collection  even its empty

```
const Details = await collectionName.find({}).exec()
```

when collection is empty there was no error just return empty array like this[]
You must create a condition to prevent an empty submission from being sent here is my solution

```
exports.somefunction = async (req, res,next) => {
  const someVariable = req.params.variable
  try {
      console.log('status',res.statusCode) **//status code is: 200**
      const Details = await collectionName.find({}).exec()
      if (Details.length===0) {
        return res.status(404).send();
      }
      res.send(Details)
  } catch {
      console.log('status',res.statusCode) **//Here also,status code is: 200**
      next(ApiError.dbError('Internal Server Error')); //middleware for error handling gives output 
                                                       //as ApiError { code: 500, message: 
                                                       //'Internal Server Error' }
      return;
  }
};
```